# Function to change text is not working jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, function

Pretty new to jQuery. I'm trying to write a function that changes the text inside a div if an on/off switch is on(green). I'm not sure why this isn't working. Here's what I've tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  if ($('.slider').is(':checked')) {
  changeText();
}

});

function changeText() {
 ('#screen span').text('00');
}
```

Here's the relevant css:

```
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 56px;
  height: 26px;
  bottom: 95px;
  left: 85px;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #990000;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
 }

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 22px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 2px;
  bottom: 2px;
  background-color: white;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #00b300;
}
```

Here's the relevant html:

```
  <div id="contents">
    <div id="screen"><span>--</span></div>
    <button id="strict"></button>
    <button id="start"></button>
  </div>

 <label class="switch">
   <input type="checkbox" checked>
   <div class="slider"></div>
 </label>
```

Also here is the code pen to the project this is from: http://codepen.io/codyreandeau/pen/dNOwwB

Any push in the right direction would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: It looks like the provided answer is pointing you in the right direction. You are also missing a `$` in your `changeText()` function, btw.

Comment: As a side note, try to avoid this kind of selector `$('#screen span')` as it could have a major performance issue.  Instead use `$('#screen').find('span');`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `div` does not provide the `checked` property because it is not an input. Give it a unique selector or use jQuery's `.prev()` method.

```
if($('.slider').prev('input').is(':checked')) {
```

Or a unique id:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="sliderCheckbox"/>

if($('#sliderCheckbox').is(':checked')) {
```

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by Ohgodwhy, the `div` doesn't provide the `checked` property. You can use this selector: `$(".switch input")`.

Also, if you want the function to run all the time the switch is turned on, you have to define a `change`-listener, otherwise your code will only run once, when the page has loaded, and the switch is never on at that point.

```
$(".switch input").on('change', function(){
 if($(this).is(':checked')){
   changeText();
 }
})
```

This inner function will run everytime the switch is pressed.

And one more thing, you have a syntax-error in your `changeText` function,
`('#contents span').text('00');` schould be `$('#contents span').text('00');`, you forgot the `$`there.

Answer (score 1):

In your function you are missing the $ from the beginning of ('#screen span').text('00'); so should be `$('#screen span').text('00');`  Also .slider is a div not an input so you should listen out for the input to be checked by giving that an ID or a class or by changing  to a

```
if ($('#mycheckbox').is(':checked')) {
  changeText();
}

  <input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox" name="mycheckbox" checked>
  <label class="slider" for="mycheckbox"></label>
```